# my test1.js is not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>                 
      <script type="text/javascript" href="test1.js"></script>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

css test2.css

```
div {
    background - color: #000000;
    height:400px;
}
```

test1.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

when the page loads the div is not fading out.
the js file is not being recognized by the browser

Comment: My suggestion first load css file and after js file in head tag

Comment: @JqueryKing Why CSS first? I want to know.

Comment: your external file of js should be call in `src="test1.js"` and not in `href` attribute

Comment: if you have many Js file is time to load that time your page is look empty visible so you need load css means it user see the image and style earlier until the page load

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="test1.js"></script>
```

Change it to..
beacause `href` used for  `<a>`  Tag .

and if u want to load external script you need to use `src='value/location'`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script reference should have src attribute not href.
Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry! Is i have to remove this answer?